# The content is loaded twice Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I have this html page and the content is loaded twice. I use routing and in my route file I put this code:

```
 path: '', component: HomeComponent,pathMatch: 'full',data: {... }

    }
```

I have also other paths. The problem is that when I go in `http://localhost:4200` the content is loaded twice. I understand this becasue I put this `<p *ngIf="execute()"></p>` in my html code and in my ts code I do this

```
execute(){
console.log("DIR");
return true;
}
```

This "DIR it shows me twice and there aren't nothing in my html page. does anyone help me?

Comment: I think this is because `ngOnChanges` runs twice in development mode and all your template bindings are checked twice, i.e. `execute()` runs twice.... check it by doing: `ng serve --prod`

Comment: @AshishRanjan you have rigth damn! and How I can resolve this in developer?

Comment: @Doflamingo19 to be sure run it with ng serve --prod flag. Check if it runs once or twice.

Comment: I run angular with ng serve!

Comment: @Doflamingo19 I also do the same, but as Ashish has said above, it happens in dev mode. I am only suggesting to see in once running with --prod flag. Just to be sure that it works with prod.

Comment: @r2018 is --prod mode it work, but I need to work also if in dev mode! because for this problem the program gives me an exception ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.

Comment: @Doflamingo19 I am assuming that you can call execute() in onInit. If yes, try to declare a variable and use it in ngIf. Because, ngOnChanges is fired twice, your function is getting called twice. I created a sample here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zaajvx

Comment: @r2018 no I can't the metohd in on init! ;

Comment: If you are trying to change some property value in `execute()` then its not a correct approach. `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` doesn't appear in production but still your application output is unpredictable. You will have to find some other way to do this..

Answer (score 0):

The condition that you place inside of an `*ngIf` directive may be executed multiple times during the component's lifetime. This is normal, as the framework needs to continually re-evaluate what should be rendered and what shouldn't as component state changes (i.e., as the change detection logic kicks in).

As has been pointed out in the comments, this behavior might be different between development mode and production, though I'm not sure that is well-defined across Angular versions.

For understanding the lifecycle of the component, you may find it more useful to define [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), and place breakpoints or tracing inside methods like `ngOnInit`. This will give you some insight as to how the framework is interacting with your component.